# asp.net dropdownlist and viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist that triggers autopostback and fires the SelectedIndexChanged change event.  Ive set viewstate to true but for some reason the selected value is not persisted between postbacks.  Ive used the dropdownlist hundreds of times but cant seem to work out why this is happening.  The items in the dropdownlist are declaratively coded e.g

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="SitePrefDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
onselectedindexchanged="SitePrefDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableViewState="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Proffesional">Proffesional</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Colorful">Colorful</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Any ideas.  Im stumped

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Proffesional.master" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="true"
CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="User Name: "></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="UserNameTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Color Scheme: ">
</asp:Label><asp:DropDownList ID="SitePrefDropDownList" runat="server" 
AutoPostBack="True" 
onselectedindexchanged="SitePrefDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableViewState="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Proffesional">Proffesional</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Colorful">Colorful</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="OKButton" runat="server" Text="OK" onclick="OKButton_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

heres the code behind

```
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Session["Template"] != null) {
        string MasterPage = String.Format("~/{0}.master", (string)Session["Template"]);
        MasterPageFile = MasterPage;
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
}

protected void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (UserNameTextBox.Text.Length != 0) {
        Session["UserName"] = UserNameTextBox.Text;
        Label Welcome = (Label)Master.FindControl("GreetingLabel");
        Welcome.Text = String.Format("Welcome, {0}!", Session["UserName"]);
    }
}

protected void SitePrefDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Session["Template"] = SitePrefDropDownList.SelectedValue;
    Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
}
}
```

Comment: where are you checking the selected value?

Comment: I cant get this. DDL fires `selectedindexchanged` event but `the selected value is not persisted between postbacks`. can you confirm if this is true?

Comment: Is this DropDownList inside of any databound container like GridView,FormView,UserControl etc. and are you calling it's `DataBind` before the event was triggered (f.e. missing `IsPostBack`-check)?

Comment: Why are you doing `Server.Transfer(Request.Path);`?

Comment: to reload the page with the new chosen masterpage.  Im following a tutorial

Comment: @Richard Banks; Read this article, this might help you to understand the problem. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7.aspx

Comment: @Richard: try taking out that line.

Comment: @Graham Clark.  That made it remember the chosen item but now the chosen masterpage is incorrect as the Page_PreInit event is called before the SelectedIndexChanged.  I guess thats why the server.transfer is in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I can think of, is you are setting some default value in your Page load event.. like..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SitePrefDropDownList.SelectedValue = "Proffesional";
}
```

Before the `SitePrefDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged` event fires in the page life cycle, the Page_load event is called first and your Default/Old value will be reset

**Edit:** Your page load should set the value like..

```
if (!Page.IsPostback)
{
   SitePrefDropDownList.SelectedValue = "Proffesional";
}
```

Comment: no i already checked that.  I also checked the load event of the dropdownlist itself.  Nothing in either

Comment: Can you please post your complete page load and form design code?

Comment: Note: if this is the correct answer i would suggest to add the solution: `if (!Page.IsPostback) {}`

Comment: @Richard Banks; Can you please tell me what you found finally ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you disabled ViewState on the page itself?

Even if the control itself has ViewState enabled, if the page has ViewState disabled then no ViewState will be recorded for *any* controls on the page - see the documentation on the [Page.EnableViewState Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstate.aspx) on MSDN.

Check to see if the `EnableViewState` property of the page has been disabled, either in the .aspx or in code behind:

```
// Any statements that look like this could be the source of your woes
this.EnableViewState = false;
Page.EnableViewState = false;

<%@ Page EnableViewState="false" ...
```

Comment: Did you test it at your end ? I have disable the viewstate at pagelevel and its still work fine to me.

Comment: EnableViewState is true on masterpage, contentpage and the control itself

Answer (score 1):

Changing masterpage causes this type of error.
Save masterpagefilename in session and set it on postbacks in preinit method.

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        this.MasterPageFile = "../../04.07.ManifestoKontrol.Web/ManifestoKontrolMasterPage.master";
        Session[String.Concat(DefaultMasterPageSessionVariableName, this.ClientID)] = this.Master.AppRelativeVirtualPath;
        base.OnPreInit(e);
    }
    else
    {
        if (Session[String.Concat(DefaultMasterPageSessionVariableName, this.ClientID)] != null)
            this.MasterPageFile = Session[String.Concat(DefaultMasterPageSessionVariableName, this.ClientID)].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you write this statement **this.MasterPageFile** in **OnPreInit**, because i am getting this error **The 'MasterPageFile' property can only be set in or before the 'Page_PreInit' event.**

Answer (score 0):

Did you see dont mistake with values and text?:

```
 <asp:ListItem Text="20" Value="20" Selected="True" />
 <asp:ListItem Text="50" Value="20" Selected="False" />
```