# Page controls losing ViewState after posting back

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, postback, viewstate

I have a bizarre problem concerning one of our .aspx pages and the controls on this page losing `ViewState` data after the page is posted back.

This is *not an issue in production* but only seems to be a problem running locally within visual studio.

Steps to reproduce:

- I visit a product page, select a product type from a drop down list (again this works fine in production and both code bases are identical) - the drop down list is set to `AutoPostback`
- I then add the product to my basket - this involves another postback
- Stepping through the code at this point I can see that many of the controls such as the drop down list has `null` for its `SelectedItem` property.

Below is a small sample of the relevant pieces of code.

Populating the product type drop down list:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    Product product = ProductsDALC.FetchBySeoUrl(Request.QueryString["url"]);

    ddlOptions.DataSource = product.ActiveVariants;
    ddlOptions.DataBind();
    ddlOptions.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please choose an option.", "-1"));

    pnlOptions.Visible = product.ActiveVariants.Count > 1;
}
```

Adding the product to the basket:

```
protected void btnAddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Product product = ProductsDALC.FetchBySeoUrl(Request.QueryString["url"]);

    int quantity = 0;
    quantity = Convert.ToInt32(ddlQuantity.SelectedValue);

    if ((ddlOptions.SelectedValue != "-1" && !ddlOptions.SelectedValue.Contains("~NA")) || product.ActiveVariants.Count == 1)
    {
        int variantId = product.DefaultVariant.Id;
        if (product.ActiveVariants.Count > 1)
        {
            variantId = Helpers.CartHelper.GetVariantIdFromDDL(ddlOptions.SelectedValue);
        }

        if (quantity > 0)
        {
            if (product.ActiveVariants.VariantById(variantId).CanBeSold)
            {
                CartItem item = product.CartItem(product.ActiveVariants.VariantById(variantId));
                item.Thumbnail = product.Imaging.MainImage.Images.ByType("Thumbnail").HtmlUrl;
                item.SeoUrl = UrlHelper.Url(UrlHelper.PageType.Product, product, false);
                CartHelper.Add(item, quantity);
                this.Master.RebindBasketWithMessage();
            }
        }
     }
}
```

After adding an item to the basket, the code skips the page load due it being a postback, and then goes into the `btnAddToCart_Click` method. Here it fails on:

```
Convert.ToInt32(ddlQuantity.SelectedValue);
```

Inspecting the value I see `""`. Checking the `SelectedItem` of this control I can see that it is `null`.

The same code fails here:

```
Product p = ProductsDALC.FetchBySeoUrl(Request.QueryString["url"]);

foreach (var variant in p.Variants)
{
      if (ddlOptions.SelectedItem.Text.Contains(variant.Description))
      {
          if (variant.OutOfStockStatusId == 2 && variant.LiveStock && variant.StockLevel <= 0)
          {
               litStockStatus.Text = "<span class=\"in-stock\">Stock in 3-5 days</span>";
          }
          else
          {
               litStockStatus.Text = "<span class=\"in-stock\">In stock</span>";
          }
      }
}
```

A null reference exception is thrown when the code reaches `ddlOptions.SelectedItem` which is also null. It's as if the controls are losing their state across postbacks but only locally?

I have searched the solution in case someone had set:

> EnableViewState="false"

And found no instances. I am at a loss for what to try next? Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: It's not the solution, but what happens if you add a TextBox control and assign some Text to it in the IsPostBack part?

Comment: You say the `SelectedItem` is null... are there _any_ items in the drop down (as in it only lost the selecteditem) or are there no items at all?

Comment: @DaveZych On visiting the page, the drop down is populated with the product types, selecting a type causes a postback, and then all items are lost from the control.

Comment: @Remy Now giving this a try thanks

Comment: There are a couple other ways to disable view state, have a look at this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679278/asp-net-dropdownlist-and-viewstate

Comment: @TheSolution Thanks, this may prove useful

Comment: @Remy, the `TextBox` value is persisted - this is weird

Comment: @Remy Unfortunately, no :(

Comment: I just hooked up a selected index changed event to the `ddlOptions` drop down list and it is not being entered

Comment: Maybe post the html? And did you try just a very simple example page with a dropdown? Just so see if that works?

Comment: @Remy I have another project that is basically a reskin of this one with the same code on this page which does not give me these issues. I've also done text comparison between both files and they are identical

Comment: Hmm, complicated. I would try to get an example working and then work backwards. Maybe just a normal dropdown on another page in this project. And maybe with other controls.